# How to automate sending faxes on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, script, automation, fax

I need some way to remotely send files for faxing by a Win7 machine.

One of the ideas I had is to use a shared dropbox folder in which I can put files which have the destination phone number as the beginning of their filename. Then, some script would monitor this folder for new files and as soon as one is founds, extract the phone number and send out the fax to that number.

Is anything like this readiily possible with some existing tools? Aletrnatively, can you think of other approaches for achieving the same end result (namely, allowing remote faxing) ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on something like that myself.  With the cost of internet faxing services, it seems a whole lot cheaper to just have everything faxed from my own phone line (especially for local calls).

Windows Fax & Scan can be run using COM if you have a bit of programming experience.  I found [this script here](http://sandlerco.com/VBScript.htm) (use the "XP And Above" one) that I started with.  The real problem is that there's very little by way of comprehensive documentation on the service that can be read through beginning to end.  I'm sure everything is buried in the nest of links in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it's a better reference than an explanation.  At least I found a second example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).